# Future or future continuous

Tags: grammar

In these sentences:

> In this programme, **we’ll learn** some related vocabulary.
>
> In this programme, **we’ll be learning** some related vocabulary.

Which one is correct?

What about these two sentences:

> It **will rain** tomorrow.
>
> It **will be raining** tomorrow.

I know the definition of each one:

- The simple future tense is a verb tense that is used when an action is expected to occur in the future and be completed.
- The future continuous tense, is a verb tense that indicates that something will occur in the future and continue for an expected length of time.

I really can't decide when use which one, because I see both of them use interchangeably?

Comment: I don't understand why we need to downvote the post of a new user when we can just kindly direct it to the appropriate site...

Comment: Downvotes are used to show that the question not useful for this site. Upvotes and Downvotes are not 'likes' and this isn't Facebook. The fact that the user is new is not a factor.

Comment: @KillingTime Well this site does say we should be "nice" to new users. Downvoting without any explanation someone new who has no idea what a downvote implies in this environment, doesn't really qualify as "nice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use them according to what you want to stress. If you simply want to convey an information in a neutral way, simple future is fine. If you want to stress that it is a continual process, or if you are thinking of ***a particular moment in the future***, when that action *will be going on*, then you can use the future continuous.

Consider

> In this programme, we’ll be ***[continuously]*** learning some related vocabulary.

> It will be raining tomorrow ***[at the time Jim will come to take us to the farm]***.